# Is there a configurable "word-of-the-day"-screensaver/ -widget

Tags: software-recommendation, dashboard-widget, screensaver

I am looking for a "word-of-the-day" screensaver or dashboard widget where I can configure (e.g. in a text file) that "words" to be displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK - there's word-of-the-day screensaver that comes packed with every Mac OS X (since Tiger). You can configure it on a "per dictionary" basis. So if you need a limited list of some words, just create your own dictionary, install it on the system and I believe you'll be able to use it in a screensaver yourself.

Comment: How do you configure it on a "per dictionary" basis? I only see English and Japanese as options even after I enabled various dictionaries, which doesn't seem to make sense but is true.